# How to react to SVG events in React Native?

Tags: react-native, svg, dom-events

**Prelude to the Question:**

I am planning to create a super simple SVG editor in React Native, with the following features:

1. add a new circle to the SVG
2. resize the circle
3. move the circle around
4. remove the circle.

What is not clear, how can I react to SVG events in React Native. (Is an SVG event the same as a DOM event (for React Native) ?)

I Googled "svg editor react native", "svg react native events" and I found:

1. https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-svg, it seems that it does not have support for events.
2. https://github.com/brentvatne/react-native-svgkit , also, does not support events yet (has it as plan though).

**The Question**:

If the user taps or drags the circle in an SVG, how can I react to that event in React Native?

EDIT1:

Further Googling indicates that SVG is not supported in React Native (yet).

Would it be easier to just use SVG + ReactJS + Cordova to accomplish this goal (i.e. write a simple SVG editor using React and deploy it to a mobile phone)?

EDIT2:

After some more Googling, it seems that http://reapp.io/ is the simplest way to go.

Answer (score 2):

> https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-svg, it seems that it does not have support for events.

It sure does, e.g.

```
<Circle cx={10} cy={10} r={20} onPress={()=>{console.log('pressed')}}/>
```

Check the [PanResponder example](https://github.com/magicismight/react-native-svg/blob/master/Example/examples/PanResponder.js) for more complex touch handling such as dragging.

> After some more googling, it seems that http://reapp.io/ is the simplest way to go.

But from what I can tell that isn't React-Native, right?

Comment: It sounded to easy to be true, but it is that easy. Thanks !